# What is the best way to launch Jenkins Server

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-cli

What is the best way to launch jenkins server in linux ?

Is it through deploying .war file in tomcat or through jenkins installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends how much traffic and number of builds.

I launch mine with tomcat 8 and nginx as the webserver. I used [this](https://devtidbits.com/2015/12/08/nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-to-apache-tomcat/) as my guide.

I launch it via cron because on a daily basis I restart the tomcat instance.

Comment: When it comes to traffic its going to be very less but the jobs  configured in jenkins uses heavy CPU and memory , in that case what do you recommend ?

Comment: high memory is going to be tough. I would try to refactor your code to lessen the memory foot print. High CPU is more manageable by setting limits on the operating system side.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both ways to launch Jenkins server but I prefer to deploy Jenkins war file inside any web container. 
It helps me to manage and upgrade Jenkins very easily.